# TypeError: Cannot call method 'toArray' of undefined while aggregatein mongo in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I get the following error while doing aggregate in node.js.

Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toArray' of undefined

```
doctorsCollection.aggregate([ 
    {$project:{"treatments._id":1, "treatments.price":1}},
    {$unwind:"$treatments"},
    {$match:{"treatments._id": parseInt(treatments[i])}}, 
    {$sort:{"treatments.price":-1}}, 
    {$limit:1} 
]).toArray(function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I have no idea what's going on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `.aggregate` method doesn't return a cursor before certain versions of the driver or if you don't specify to use the cursor as an option. Pass the callback directly to get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`.aggregate` documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate) for the node.js MongoDB driver, the method does not return a cursor unless you specify for it to return a cursor as an option. By default it will return `null` so the `.toArray` method doesn't work / make sense.

There are several ways to handle it and the documentation provides a ton of examples. In your case you can add `{cursor: {batchSize: 1}}` as the second argument to `.aggregate` and it will work.